# UI for splitting value into multiple chunks

Tags: web

In an application I am developing, the user needs to schedule production of an order into multiple chunks to schedule on certain days. Examples below:

Order X totals 120 min of production. Any of the below should be possible

User can create 6 chunks of 20 minutes

User can create 1 chunk of 100 minuted and one of 20 minutes

User can have only one chunk of 120 minutes

What would be the best ui for this?

Thanks!

Comment: You should provide an example to evaluate rather than asking to design a UI for you

Comment: Some questions: can user choose any number or chunks or is there any limitation (e.g., min 1 chunck - max 6 chunks)? Do all chunks have the same duration or can users specify a different duration for single chunks? Who are your target users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the similar task having in mind rating UI, watch [live example](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/rating.html) or static picture for reference:
[image]

Then your design could look like this:

[image: http://s28.postimg.org/kmhsdgsh9/screenshot_77.png]

**Notes**:

- Chunks are selected with one click
- Once a chunk was selected, you
  re-calculate available free chunks and disable the excessive ones
- Provide UI element for resetting the selected chunks
- Provide units labeling to be more clear for users

Answer (score 0):

First thought would be provide visual representations of time chunks that the user can drag over to different days. Think of 120 minutes divided into 6 20 minute chunks (boxes) that the user can drag over to the appropriate time slots.

The build for this is rather straight-forward. I would also provide text boxes to allow users to type the data in if they so preferred.